# Spontaneous right click without touching mouse

Tags: macos, mouse

I sign in to my iMac running OS X Lion. Since this morning I am continuously seeing popups as if I right-clicked my mouse.

I changed my keyboard and mouse from wireless to wired, but the problem persists.

I checked all processes running and all seemed to be normal.

Does anybody know how to fix this? Am I the victim of a virus? The only change I made to my iMac is installing Skype on it.

Comment: Please please ignore this oh so stupid question!!
I have a Wacom board connected to my iMac and the power supply of my laptop was laying half over the wacom board creating some induction or whatever that caused the strange behaviour.... I'm ashamed for having asked this question... but maybe someone can benefit from it in the future! So I leave it out here

Comment: Hey, don't be ashamed. The same thing happens to me at least once a month ;). So that it's easier for other people to find what caused the problem, please post this as an answer down below. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: The #1 cause of an issue with technology is a goofy oversight by the user. I can't tell you how many hours I've spent searching a server for the cause of a failure, only to find I was missing a single semicolon in the config file.

Comment: @Jerome Could you please put your comment in an answer and accept it as the answer to your own question?